# Among Schengen countries, which has the "easiest" requirements for getting permanent residence?

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, residency, schengen, europe

I am an international student from South Asia, studying for a Master's (Computer Science) in a Schengen country.

I want to get "permanent residence" in any of the Schengen countries: Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, and Switzerland.

For me, which country will be the "easiest" to getting Permanent
Residence and what will be the procedure?

Comment: Define "easiest"?

Comment: Easitest means -- less time to stay, no need to learn native language of that specific country, very easy to get full time job for South-asian people, etc

Comment: anyone?........

Answer (score 3):

- Time: Almost every country in the Schengen area requires at least 5 years of residence to become a permanent resident, so I'd say time-wise you can choose any country you want.
- Language: easiest to learn is arguably Dutch, assuming you already speak English. Spanish is also not that hard and widely useful around the world.
- Ease of getting a job: the richer the country, the easier it is to find a job. Germany, Norway, Switzerland, Sweden, Netherlands and Belgium are perfectly good choices. Check out EU's unemployment rates and go for the countries with the lowest unemployment.

However be aware that being a permanent resident of the EU is not too useful once you leave the country in question, as other countries won't automatically grant you residency based on your residency in a different EU country. Only being a citizen grants you the true privilege of relocating anywhere within the EU at will. You are therefore looking at spending 10+ years in the country in question, so I recommend choosing wisely from the beginning.

Comment: I won't leave the country (I will just spend 1-2 months per year outside of the Schengen country). If I get "indefinite" time of residence (along with permission to work), that's is Enough for me.

Comment: Is there any Schengen country for which I do Not have to learn the native/additional language?

Comment: @R.Zam being a permanent resident won't allow you to work in other EU countries.

Comment: But it allows to work in that specific Schegen country?

Comment: Yes it does. But you can also work there if you have a regular work permit

Comment: @R.Zam as for languages - no, there's no country in the Schengen area that would give a regular worker permanent residence without at least basic command of the local language

Comment: How will I spend 5 years in a Schengen country? (I am already doing Masters, and I want to move to another Schengen country)

Comment: anyone there?...

Comment: In which country are you doing Masters?

Comment: The country you're doing your Masters in matters. There may be a provision so that you can stay and work there. This exists in France. But you'd have to have a stable situation (a job and paying taxes) for many years before you'd become permanent. It's actually easier to become a citizen than to get a 10 year residence permit at this point.

Comment: @SayedA.  I am doing Masters in Czech Republic

Comment: @lafemmecosmique . I don't want to stay in Czech Republic.

Comment: @R.Zam finish your masters, find a job that is willing to arrange a visa for you and then move.

Comment: I cannot get a english speaking job in Czech Republic

Comment: Dutch is easy to learn? According to people who have tried, it's the most  difficult language in Europe, excluding ugro-finnish ones... so it depends...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo see the US army language classification: https://www.atlasandboots.com/foreign-service-institute-language-difficulty/. Not sure why any English speaker would find Dutch particularly difficult to learn.

Comment: @JonathanReez note the **English** speaker part. It works only for native English speakers, for others it makes not much sense. Many people I know claim Dutch to be 'almost impossible' to spell...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo it works for any fluent English speaker. And you don't need to know the spelling precisely to speak the language. These days you don't even need to know the spelling to write thanks to auto correct.

Comment: Please define "absolutely useless".

Comment: @hippietrail done

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica: Much better - thanks!